# Topology of figure 8 and torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

So I know what are the fundamental groups of a figure-8 ($S^1\vee S^1$) and a torus ($T^2$), and I am wondering that, there is an inclusion $i:S^1\vee S^1 \rightarrow T^2,$ so how should I write out the induced inclusion $i_*:\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1)\rightarrow\pi_1(T^2)$? Thanks!

Comment: It's the abelianization map from $F_2$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you explain where does $F_2$ come from? I think the fundamental group of the figure-8 is the free group of two generators (Z*Z).

Comment: That's what $F_2$ means.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: And one more question, is it possible to write this homomorphism out explicitly?

Comment: It is quite explicit already; it sends the two generators of $F_2$ to the two generators of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: I see. Thanks! So is there any theorem that guarantees the uniqueness of such map (so I mean is there any other possible homomorphisms besides the abelianization)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "uniqueness" here. There are many diffferent maps $S^1 \vee S^1 \to T^2$ and they correspond to different maps on fundamental groups in general. I have a specific map in mind that involves projecting the first resp. second copy of $S^1$ in $S^1 \vee S^1$ to the first resp. second copy of $S^1$ in $S^1 \times S^1$ but it's certainly not unique.

Comment: So I can see that there are multiple homomorphisms from Z*Z to ZxZ by sending generators to generators, but in this case can we figure out under how the generators of $F_2$ are mapped under this spesific $i_*$?

Comment: What specific $i_{\ast}$? The one I described or another one? The one I described has the property, as I mentioned, that it sends the two generators of $F_2$ to the two generators of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, more or less by construction.

Comment: Yes I get your idea of construction, but I guess I am confused that, when we say sending the two generators to the two generators of ZxZ, do we need to clarify which two generators of ZxZ (because the generating set is not unique).

Comment: I mean the generators $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ (the "standard basis").

Comment: Is it necessary to map to this pair of generators?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "necessary." Again, there are many maps $S^1 \vee S^1 \to T^2$.

Comment: So I mean could $i_*$ be a homomorphism mapping $a$ and $b$ to some other generators of Z*Z, say $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ (or some other pairs)?

Comment: Sorry I it's some other generators of ZxZ.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And in fact $i_{\ast}$ could map $a$ and $b$ to any two elements of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ whatsoever.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!